# Did Arjuna marry a widow? Was Ulupi a widow?

Tags: mahabharata, marriage, arjuna, sex

Ulupi was the daughter of a Naga King. She had a son named Iraban. His father was Arjuna. What was the marital status of Ulupi during her marriage with Arjuna? Was she a virgin? or a widow?

Comment: How does this logic come about? Arjuna married Ulupi and had a son called Iravan - where does widow come into the picture?

Comment: Arjuna and Ulupi never married. He spent one night with her and had a son named Iravan. Ulupi was a widow when Arjuna met her.

Comment: @kiran according to different hindu marriage system, if you had sex, then actually you are marrying her. There are 7 types of marriages. By the way, where it is mentioned that Ulupi was a widow??? That's what I want to know.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay This handsome and valiant son of Arjuna, named Iravat, was begotten upon the daughter of the king of the Nagas by the intelligent Partha. Her husband having been slain by Garuda, she became helpless, and of cheerless soul. https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06091.htm

Comment: @Kiran Thank you so much. The next lines also clearly say Partha accepted her as a wife. Can you please post it as an answer with the paragraph no. etc. so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Kiran So, I think widow marriage was acceptable in ancient India. It is not something new! That is intesresting.

Comment: @Kiran interesting find!

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay Posted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arjuna spent one night with Ulupi and begot a son named Iravat. Ulupi's husband was killed by Garuda a long time ago and she was living in her father's palace. Arjuna gave Ulupi the status of a wife even though there was no official marriage between them. [Here is the citation from Bhishma Parva:](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06091.htm)

> This handsome and valiant son of Arjuna, named Iravat, was begotten
> upon the daughter of the king of the Nagas by the intelligent Partha.
> Her husband having been slain by Garuda, she became helpless, and of
> cheerless soul. Childless as she was, she was bestowed (upon Arjuna)
> by the high-souled Airavat. Partha accepted her for wife, coming to
> him as she did under the influence of desire. It was thus that that
> son of Arjuna was begotten upon the wife of another.

After the kurukshetra war, Ulupi lived in Hastinapura palace until Pandavas left for heaven.

Comment: "even though there was no official marriage" - Gandharva vivaha = official marriage (only for Kshatriyas though)

Comment: @mar There is no mention of Gandharva marriage also

Comment: sex = gandharva marriage.

Answer (score 5):

Ulupi was not a widow as she says

> [image]

This verse is in Adiparva, chapter 213, verse number 20

Here is the English translation from [The Mahabharata of Krishna Dwaipayana Vyasa translated by Kisari Mohan Ganguly](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01217.htm) (Book I: Adi Parva, Arjuna Vanavasa Parva Section CCXVI)

"Hearing these words of Arjuna, Ulupi answered, 'There is a Naga of the name of Kauravya, born in the line of Airavata. I am, O prince, the daughter of that Kauravya, and my name is Ulupi. O tiger among men, beholding thee descend into the stream to perform thy ablutions, I was deprived of reason by the god of desire. **O sinless one, I am still unmarried. Afflicted as I am by the god of desire on account of thee, O thou of Kuru's race, gratify me today by giving thyself up to me.**'

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Please add translation of the verse and reference as well.

Comment: @Aditya Dwivedi She simply lied to Arjuna!!! Or you may say she did not disclose the whole truth, which is kind of lying. At that moment she was not romantically attached to anybody, that's what she said, which is true. But she presented the fact in a way that sounds she was never attached to anyone, which is a lie. See the comment of Kiran.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - Did Vyasji say she lied ? Or are you projecting your beliefs?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - I am saying that she never said that she was not married before. Can it not be the case that she had not given her heart to deceased husband ?

Comment: @Aditya Dwivedi - From where is this quote ? Parva/Section, Verse Number ?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - I still dont see how you come to the conclusion that she lied to Arjuna or for that matter hide her previous marriage. It can be common knowledge

Comment: Uloopi being a widow is mentioned in Bhishma Parva. Her husband was killed by Garuda.